# Mail does not show up on the iPhone, only online on the email's website or in other third party tools

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app, email

In the iPhone Mail app, I got two mails of the same sender in my "Unknown" folder. I then moved them both to my "Inbox" folder since I trusted the sender. But looking up the inbox, I found only one of the two. I would normally oversee this. But I needed that second mail to work with at once, so that I had to open my mail provider's website online in my iPhone to get it back, and later, I could also read it in Thunderbird and Outlook, but it did not come back in the iPhone Mail app.

These should be roughly about the same thing:

- [Emails Received but not Visible in Inbox with IOS 10 on iphone](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7701735) - but it reads as if there is just a main guide on how to get mails, not about missing mails.
- [How to Fix the Emails Not Appearing in the Mail App on iOS 17](https://www.tenorshare.com/ios-10/how-to-fix-the-emails-not-appearing-in-mail-app-on-ios-10.html)  - but it sounds like updating is the only fix here, and I update the OS whenever it asks for it. And it also is about iOS 10 but writes iOS 17 to catch some clicks for some cross-sales.
- [iphone mail not showing mail that shows up in Apple Mail mailboxes on iMac](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250491578) made me check Settings -> Email -> Accounts -> at the bottom: Download new data -> and the settings are right, on "Download".

My iOS is 15.7.8 on an iPhone 7.

How can I get this missing email (and if there are, any other missing emails) back to the Mail app?

PS: At least, I *did* see the later missing mail in the first place. If that holds true for any incoming mail, I should just read all mails in the first place where they come in or check any needed mail that I moved in its new folder. Therefore, this bug is not as bad or dangerous as it sounds. When I search through my mails in my iPhone Mail app, I should still keep in mind that there might be some very few mails missing in the search output.

Comment: I presume you have deleted **ALL** accounts on the phone and re-added them? Failing that I would be tempted to back-up, wipe and then restore the phone, with no mail accounts added to the Apple mail.app. Wiping the phone deletes temporary files and in some cases I have found it helps with apps acting wonky.

Comment: @SteveChambers Ah that "turn off and on" again thingy :). Yes, I guess you are right about it: if I removed all of the accounts and added them again, I am quite sure that all of the mails would be in there, since this was just an error "on the run". This is most likely the only answer. See the [Emails Received but not Visible in Inbox with IOS 10 on iphone](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7701735) with 192 finding the question helpful and nobody finding the answer helpful. If you answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete ALL accounts on the phone and re-add them. I have found that one troubleshooting step in mail.app to fix a multitude of issues.

Failing that I would be tempted to back-up, wipe and then restore the phone, with no mail accounts added to the Apple mail.app. Wiping the phone deletes temporary files and in some cases I have found it helps with apps acting wonky.